# How to validate json schema for a particular naming?

Tags: java, json, schema

**Updated:**

Please, take a look at following.

For this example, it has two pretty the same objects inside. With two fields for each of them - **id** and **is_deleted**.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "delete_count": 1,
        "status": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "is_deleted": true
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "is_deleted": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Let's imagine 2 different occasions:

- every **id** has changed to **uid**
- **status** has changed to **stat**, the only **is_deleted** field has changed to just **deleted**(if this is possible. let's imagine it is)

So, I have a schema for this payload. But, it checks for field types not for field names.

it uses com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv

Answer (score 1):

JsonObject has a method which returns true if key exist `public boolean has(java.lang.String key)`

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Your_STRING);
if (jsonObj.has("org_id")) {
      //Do stuff
}
```

for more details you can check below -

[check key exist](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

try to verify if **org_id** exists, the question isn't clear!.

Comment: could you you please suggest particular way I can implement it?